# How do I use SQL's JOIN to select column A if column B = column C?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use SQL's JOIN query to select something from my members table if something from the friends table equals something else from the members table.

Let me expand on that a little bit.

If `friends.user_id` *or* `friends.friend_id = $variable`, then `select members.username where $variable = members.id`, and then put all of that data into an array (`$array = array()`. Nothing fancy).

I have no idea where to start (I'm new to this, if you couldn't tell)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  m.username
FROM    members m INNER JOIN
    friends f   ON  m.id IN (f.user_id,f.friend_id)
WHERE   m.id = $variable
```

I noted that the above might return more than 1 entry based on the data in your tables, so here is another example.

```
SELECT  m.username
FROM 
members m
WHERE m.id = 2    
AND     EXISTS  (
            SELECT  1 
            FROM    friends f 
            WHERE m.id IN (f.user_id,f.friend_id)
        )
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b06/3)

The above example will show you the difference between the 2 statements.

This article has some nice visual representation of joins, and is always handy to have around.

[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: This answer does not seem to be correct. OP asks for *array* of users or friends with given id. In your solution, it will always return single id (since members.id seems to be primary key).

Comment: **nevermind!** I just changed m.id = $variable to m.id <> $variable. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you had to change your query to use `<>` instead of `=`, that means there is something seriously wrong. You might have gotten lucky and it happens to work on your current input. But it is dangerous proposition. At any rate, it considered bad practice to accept answers which are simply incorrect or wrong. You should edit this answer to use `<>` exactly as you used for working solution - then answer acceptance is ok, because then it becomes correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT members.username
FROM   members, friends
WHERE  (friends.user_id = members.id
        OR friends.friend_id = members.id) AND
       members.id = $variable
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT m.username
FROM members m, friends f
WHERE m.id = f.user_id
  AND $variable IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7df6/1).